# iPhone equivalent of -doCommandBySelector:?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I want to push something onto the iPhone's responder chain. That is, I want to send a selector to a `UIResponder` subclass and, if it doesn't respond to said selector, have it pass it on to its `nextResponder`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the docs for -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:].